# Matrix multiplication and tensorial summation convention

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I'm reading this introduction to tensors: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403252.pdf, specifically rules concerning summation convention (ref. page 13):

> **Rule 1**. In correctly written tensorial formulas free indices are
>   written on the same level (upper or lower) in both sides of the
>   equality. Each free index has only one entry in each side of the
>   equality.
>
> **Rule 2**. In correctly written tensorial formulas each summation index
>   should have exactly two entries: one upper entry and one lower entry.
>
> **Rule 3**. For any double indexed array with indices on the same level
>   (both upper or both lower) the first index is a row number, while the
>   second index is a column number. If indices are on different levels
>   (one upper and one lower), then the upper index is a row number, while
>   lower one is a column number.

I have a doubt on applying these rules to matrix multiplication though. Let $A$ and $B$ be matrices and let's represent their elements as $A_{ij}$ and $B^{jk}$. If $C=AB$, then

$$C_i^k = A_{ij}B^{jk}$$

where $j$ is summed over. But on the LHS, $k$ clearly represents the column index, and $i$ the row index. You can even check it yourself by considering $A$ and $B$ as $2\times 2$ matrices. According to rule 3 though, it's supposed to be the opposite since $i$ is the subscript and $k$ the superscript.

Is there a way to resolve the inconsistency between the $3$ rules here, or am I missing something? Because if this convention doesn't even apply to something as simple as matrix multiplication, then it seems pretty useless.